# Is it possible to disable the splash welcome screen in Office 2008 on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, microsoft-office-2008

I don't like splash screens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the startup splash screen then no you can't.

[image]

That particular screen is used to show it's still launching while it loads the components and if necessary optimizes the font menu. If you're referring to the Project Browser that starts up right way - yes you can.

To stop the Project Browser from showing up go to Preferences of whichever Office application is open, go to the General section and uncheck "Show Project Gallery at startup"

Comment: I meant the startup splash screen. I don't mind that it's loading components in the background, what annoys me is that the splash image steals focus and then blocks what I'm looking at underneath it, and then the loading often lags my system to the point that I can't return focus to the window underneath it, hence wasting precious seconds of work! Gaa!  :)

Comment: @Philip: If it's any condolence I hear you completely - it's why I avoid opening or quitting an Office app once it's open.